# Error de redireccionamiento en middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy conociendo el framework de Laravel y en la practica me tope con un error de logica que no logro entender muy bien, resulta que estoy configurando un middleware que filtre a un usuario si su informacion no se encuentra completa  y despues de dias de dolor de cabeza lo logre con la ayuda esta comunidad, pero me tope con un detalle y es que si el usuario completo su formulario se inserta en la base de datos un 1 en la columna wizard, pero este puede seguir ingresando directamente a la ruta si lo desea y volver a introducir otra vez su informacion, cosa que no quiero que suceda, o sea, si el usuario ya lo completo no pueda ingresar a esta ruta de nuevo nunca, para ello cree una ruta:

```
Route::get('/denied', 'DeniedController@index')->name('denied');
```

con su respectivo controlador que se encarga de redireccionar al inicio con un mensaje de error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DeniedController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

el detalle se que se encuentra en mi middleware porque si el usuario ya completo su formulario no deberia pasar, estoy muy confundido de tantas formas que he intentado que esto suceda, espero haberme explicado y puedan ayudarme a filtrar bien

El codigo del middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use App\Empresa;

class WizardVerification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
          $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
          if($data->wizard == 0){
             return redirect('wizard');
          }elseif ($data->wizard == 1) {
            return redirect('denied')->with('status', 'No tienes permiso de ingresar a esta ruta porque ya configuraste tu empresa');
          }

}}
```

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que en tu controlador DeniedController solo estas ocupando el middleware auth, debes agregar tambien el middleware WizardVerification. Revisa también que el middleware este registrado en el archivo kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

Debes regisrar tu middleware en el kernel que encontraras en `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ... // Otros middlewares
        'wizard'           => WizardVerification::class,
    ];
```

y después puedes usarlo bien por controlador en el constructos como haces con auth

```
    $this->middleware('wizard');
```

o bien por ruta

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['wizard']], function () {
    // Aquí las rutas afectadas
});
```